# how long can I keep thawed corned beef in my refrigerator?

Tags: food-safety, thawing, corned-beef

I took a corned beef out of the freezer and thawed it in my fridge. How long can I keep it before it has to be cooked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How long can I store a food in the pantry, refrigerator, or freezer?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/21068/how-long-can-i-store-a-food-in-the-pantry-refrigerator-or-freezer)

Comment: I don't know that it *is* a duplicate of that one, given corned beef is partially(?) cured, and nothing listed at that link covers that ground that I can see.